# Fortran: segmentation fault

Tags: fortran, openmp, f2py

I know I once made a similar topic, but that one was different. This time, adding a print statement does not change whether or not I get a segfault.

```
    call omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads())
    !$omp parallel do  &
    !$omp default(firstprivate) &
    !$omp private(present_surface) &
    !$omp lastprivate(fermi)
    do m = 1, fourth 
        do n = 1, third
            do j = 1, second
                do i = 1, first
                    !current angle is phi[i,j,ii,jj]
                    !we have to find the current fermi surface
                    present_surface = 0.
                    do a = 1, fourth    
                        if (angle(i,j,n,m) == angle_array(a)) then
                            present_surface = surface(a)
                        end if
                    end do 
                    if (radius(i,j,n,m) >= present_surface) then 
                        fermi(i,j,n,m) = 0.
                    else 
                        fermi(i,j,n,m) = 1.
                    end if          
                end do      
            end do      
        end do
    end do  
    !$omp end parallel do
```

I'm not sure about the lastprivate(fermi) statement, but it doesn't matter at this moment. shared gives the same behaviour.

So, I run this script with 'first, second, third, fourth' being increased. Typical output:

```
[10] Time elapsed is 0.001 [s].
[15] Time elapsed is 0.002 [s].
[20] Time elapsed is 0.005 [s].
./compile: line 2:  4310 Segmentation fault      python fortran_test.py
```

Well, how to proceed. I looked at gdb python; run fortran_test.py, and found:

```
(gdb) run fortran_test.py 
Starting program: /usr/bin/python fortran_test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7fffed9b0700 (LWP 4251)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe8ba5700 (LWP 4252)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe83a4700 (LWP 4253)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe7ba3700 (LWP 4254)]
[10] Time elapsed is 0.008 [s].
[15] Time elapsed is 0.004 [s].
[20] Time elapsed is 0.005 [s].

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffe7ba3700 (LWP 4254)]
0x00007fffe8dc0bb7 in __populate_MOD_fermi_integrand._omp_fn.0 () at     populate.f90:31
31                              do n = 1, third
```

If I change things in the inner loop - for instance, removing the j,i loops and putting them to a constant - then I just get the segfault at a different line.

I *think* this has something to do with memory, because it triggers as N increases. However, the things I've tried (export GOMP_STACKSIZE, OMP_STACKSIZE, ulimit) haven't fixed it, and I see no difference using them. (For the time being, I removed them).

Finally, the command to compile (it is in f2py):

```
 f2py --fcompiler=gfortran --f90flags="-fopenmp -g" -lgomp -m -c populate populate.f90
```

As you can see, I'm quite stuck. I hope some of you know how to solve the problem.

My aim is to have N=100 run quickly (hence the openMP fortran function), but this shouldn't matter for the fortran code, should it?

If you're wondering, 4GB ram and my swap is 3.1G (Linux Swap / Solaris).

Thank you!

Comment: Your other post fixed it, but to answer this: two things; first, if clauses to check, and two, run it in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default(firstprivate) lastprivate(fermi)` means that each thread receives a private copy of `angle`, `radius`, and `fermi`, with each being of size `first x second x third x fourth`. In my experience, private arrays are always allocated on the stack, even when the option to automatically turn big arrays into heap arrays is given. Your code most likely crashes because of insufficient stack space.

Instead of having everything private, you should really take a look at the data dependency and pick the correct data-sharing classes. `angle`, `angle_array`, `surface`, and `radius` are never written to, therefore they all should be `shared`. `present_surface` is being modified and should be `private`. `fermi` is written to, but never at the same location by more than one thread, therefore it should also be `shared`. Also, note that `lastprivate` won't have the expected result as it makes available the value of the corresponding variable that it has in the thread that executes the logically last iteration of the `m`-loop. `first`, `second`, `third`, and `fourth` are simply treated as constants and should be `shared`. The loop variables, of course, are `private`, but that is automated by the compiler.

```
!$omp parallel do private(present_surface)
do m = 1, fourth 
    do n = 1, third
        do j = 1, second
            do i = 1, first
                !current angle is phi[i,j,ii,jj]
                !we have to find the current fermi surface
                present_surface = 0.
                do a = 1, fourth    
                    if (angle(i,j,n,m) == angle_array(a)) then
                        present_surface = surface(a)
                    end if
                end do 
                if (radius(i,j,n,m) >= present_surface) then 
                    fermi(i,j,n,m) = 0.
                else 
                    fermi(i,j,n,m) = 1.
                end if          
            end do      
        end do      
    end do
end do  
!$omp end parallel do
```

Comment: That was splendid. I thought that putting all those things to firstprivate meant that the filled-in-data would get passed to the thread, but would save up memory because they wouldn't be write enabled. I've been doing it wrong for a while! Thank you. So [shared] variables remain on the ...heap? I'm assuming stack means the thread-cache.

Comment: oh, and 5.194 for N=100, which is great. (was over 5 minutes for the python function).

Comment: Stack means stack - each thread has one of its own. Local variables are allocated on the stack by decrementing the stack pointer with the size of the variable (the stack grows downwards on x86). Even if you don't read or write stack variables, the pointer is still decremented and could overflow (underflow?).

Answer (score 0):

A very possible reason is the stack limit. First run `ulimit -s` to check the stack limit for the process. You can use `ulimit -s unlimited` to set it as ulimited. Then if it still crashes, try to increase the stack for OPENMP by setting `OMP_STACKSIZE` environmental variable to a huge value, like `100MB`.

Intel has a discussion at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors. It has more information of stack and heap memory.

Comment: "However, the things I've tried (export GOMP_STACKSIZE, OMP_STACKSIZE, ulimit) haven't fixed it, and I see no difference using them."

Comment: Read document carefully first https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html   or  http://www.bgu.ac.il/intel_fortran_docs/compiler_f/main_for/mergedProjects/optaps_for/common/optaps_par_var.htm  `Sets the number of bytes to allocate for each OpenMP thread to use as the private stack for the thread.Recommended size is 16M.Use the optional suffixes: B (bytes), K (Kilobytes), M (Megabytes), G (Gigabytes), or T (Terabytes) to specify the units. If only value is specified and B, K, M, G, or T is not specified, then size is assumed to be K (Kilobytes).` It must be a value but not "unlimited"

Comment: Even if that fixes the crash the OP's program is still doing a lot of unnecessary work by copying so much data on each thread's stack. The accepted answer correctly shows that that is just plain wasteful and it should really be said. But 1. `unlimited` is well known to fix these issues, 2. the OP also tested GOMP_STACKSIZE and OMP_STACKSIZE, 3. the OP is likely using GCC, and not Intel (and hence GOMP_). 4. if it was really just about increasing the stack I would have closed the question as a duplicate, this fix is well known here.